# How to Keep from Receiving a NullReferenceException when Accessing the Result of a Web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am getting a response in form of a SOAP message from a web service. I don't know on beforehand what nodes are available (some but not all).
Lets say I get data about a customer

Name
City

and in the code I can write

```
string name = "";
string city = "";
name = customer.name;
city = customer.city;
```

If the city returns an empty string I can handle that with writing

```
city = (string)customer.city;
```

instead. But sometimes the response doesn't include a city node and then I get the NullReferenceException was unhandled error, how can I fix this?

Comment: You don't have to initialize name and city to the empty string, since you're going to set them in the next few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually asking for this:

```
city = customer != null ? customer.city : "";
```

?

Incidentally, casting a `string` to a `string` as you have here: `(string)""` (the equiavlent of `(string)customer.City` when `customer.City == ""`) is not necessary.  (Unless of course `customer.City` is somehow actually not a `string`.)

Comment: Incidentally, this is called a ternary operation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ?? operator.  This is assuming the customer object will always not be null.

`string city = customer.city ?? ""`